# Fill database table with data from config files on app startup

Tags: sqlite, haskell, yesod

I want the initial database state in my yesod web app to be defined by config files that are parsed on app startup. My current approach to achieve this compiles, but doesn't seem to do anything, I suspect this is because the database may not be ready for use at that point or needs to be accessed differently.

```
import System.Directory 
import Data.Ini    

-- | The @main@ function for an executable running this site.
appMain :: IO ()
appMain = do
  settings <- loadYamlSettingsArgs
      [configSettingsYmlValue]
      useEnv

  foundation <- makeFoundation settings

  loadConfigs -- | load configs and fill db

  app <- makeApplication foundation
  runSettings (warpSettings foundation) app


loadConfigs :: IO ()
loadConfigs = do allFiles <- getDirectoryContents "/config"
                 let filtered = filter (isSuffixOf ".cfg") allFiles
                 forM_ filtered parseConfig

parseConfig :: String -> IO ()
parseConfig fileName = do 
                        res <- readIniFile fileName
                        case res of
                            Left msg -> do
                                return ()
                            Right ini -> do
                                let name = fromRight (pack "-") $ lookupValue (pack "name")  (pack "-") ini
                                db $ insert (User name "" "")
                                return ()

-- | Run DB queries
db :: ReaderT SqlBackend (HandlerT App IO) a -> IO a
db = handler . runDB
```

Could you please enlighten an unexperienced haskeller? Thanks!

Comment: I'm suspicious of that use of `db`. I also don't know where it's defined or what it does. I should add that I don't know Yesod, maybe it's a standard thing from its scaffolding?

Comment: You're right, I added the definition above.